# PHP XPath wild card search

Tags: php, html, xpath

I want to retrieve all the content in a div element in HTML. I am using PHP and XPath to do it. Here is the query:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($uri);
$xpath= new DOMXPath($doc);
$text_content =
$xpath->query("/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/*");
```

I used wild card "*" to retrieve all elements (normal text, div, img, p etc.) under this div(div[5]), but when I printed the $text_content, I found out that it only stored all the div elements.

What is the correct way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.../*` will only retrieve the nodes that are immediate descendents of that file `div[5]` in the xpath query. e.g

```
 ... rest of document ...
     <div id="5">
        <p>hello <span>there</span></p>
     </div>
```

In this simplified example, your query will retrieve the `<p>`, because it's an immediate descent of the `<div>`. It will not bring back the `<span>`, because that's a grandchild of the `<div>`

To get all the descendants, regardless of level, you'd want

```
.../div[5]//*
          ^^---note doubled slashes
```

`//` is short-hand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, would return the span.

Comment: Hi @Marc B, 

Thanks for your tip. It is working now. Can I ask one more question? How do I retrieve the src attribute when I detect a img node? I know there is nodeName and nodeValue for each DOMNodeList item, is there any method that I can examine the other attributes of this item?

Comment: `$node->getAttribute('src')`